# Como cambiar el aspecto de la imagen de fondo de una ContentPage en .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Estoy creando una aplicación multiplataforma con .NET MAUI y al momento de aplicar la propiedad *`BackgroundImageSource`* al *`ContentPage`* la muestra correctamente pero adaptada a la pantalla en la que se esta mostrando, si yo quisiera que mantuviera el mismo tamaño en todo tipo de pantallas como podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando el atributo Resize, busca en el archivo de tu proyecto, .csproj, la imagen, por ejemplo:

```
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\logo.svg" Resize="false" />
```

También puedes agregarle un tamaño base:

```
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\logo.jpg" BaseSize="376,678" />
```

Checa la documentación a ver si eso puede ayudarte: [Agregar imágenes en MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/images)